# Assigning letters as row names in R

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and I am currently working on a homework problem that I can't seem to figure out and I'm hoping that someone here can help to point me in the right direction.  The assignment states to create a matrix with 25 rows and 800 columns with the numbers being taken from a chi-squared distribution with 5 degrees of freedom.  I have done this correctly (I think) with:

```
chi <- rchisq(20000, 5)
chi
```

I am supposed to assign row names as the first 25 letters of the alphabet, in lower case.  This is the part that I am stuck on.  I have tried using:

```
rownames(chi) <- letters[1:25]
```

I feel like this is correct but the problem is that I am trying to set rownames on an object with no dimensions.  So I guess my problem lies with me using n=20000 in the original line and not actually setting dimensions?

Comment: You should probably get your matrix into shape first, for example by using the `dim` or `matrix` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the matrix.  The result of `rchisq()` is just a simple numeric vector.  We can create the matrix and set the row names all in the `matrix()` function.

```
chi <- matrix(rchisq(20000, 5), 25, dimnames = list(letters[-26], NULL))
```

Alternatively, you can use `dim()` to add the dimension attribute after creating `chi`, then set the row names.

```
chi <- rchisq(20000, 5)
dim(chi) <- c(25, 800)
rownames(chi) <- letters[-26]
```